# Apache directive returning some static content directly from configuration

Tags: apache

I am looking for Apache httpd directive, that would immediately return some plaintext content ("System was not configured yet") or at least immediately generate 500 exception (so I can use ErrorDocument 500 'System was not configured yet').

Is there something I could use, or do I need to use some files on dics for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a file for that plus error document setting for all possible URLs:

```
Alias /katello "/usr/share/katello/public/"
<Location /katello>
  DirectoryIndex not_configured.txt
  ErrorDocument 404 'Katello was not configured yet, please run katello-configure'
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this document :

The JK Connector is a web server component used to invisibly integrate Tomcat with a web server such as Apache or IIS. Communication between the web server and Tomcat is via the JK protocol (also known as the AJP protocol).

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/jk.html

Hope it can help you!

Edit:

you can also see this link:

http://www.viart.com/activating_friendly_urls.html.html

How to make a redirect to 404 custom page if fURLs are enabled

To make a redirect to a custom 404 page please do the following steps:

- Login to your ViArt Shop Admin console.
- Navigate to Administration > CMS > Custom Pages and create a 404 custom page

Click 'Update' to save the changes.

- Access your site via any FTP client program and open your .htaccess file.
- Insert the following string at the very beginning of the file:

ErrorDocument 404 /friendly_url.php
- Save the changes and upload the updated file to the root folder of your shop.

- Open the file 'friendly_url.php' (located in the root folder) and find such a code:

$is_friendly_url = false;
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
exit;

-Replace this code with the following:

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
header("Status: 200 OK");
set_get_param("page", '404');
include_once('page.php');
return;
where '404' is the name of your custom page as created in your ViArt shop Admin console.

Note: If you do not want to create a custom 404 page in your Admin panel please add the following code to your 'friendly_url.php' file:

$echo_string = implode("",file('http://example.com/404_text.txt'));
echo $echo_string;
exit;
where '404_text.txt' is any empty text file saved in the root folder of your shop.

- Save the changes in the 'friendly_url.php' file and upload the updated file to the root folder of your shop.
- Open your browser and type something like: http://example.com/404, where example.com equals your actual site URL and 404 is the name of your custom 404 page. If you did everything correctly you will see your 404 custom page.